# How to cross reference files in Python?

Tags: python, import

I have a mainscript.py and a foo.py file that I wanna import to use some functions in it, but the maainscript.py need variables from the foo.py . I tried to normally import one script to the other and using the multiprocessing module. 
I always get this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'somefunction' from 'mainscript'
```

Here are the ways i tried:

in mainscript.py I tried:

```
from foo import firstPoint

def somefunction(firstPoint, someArgs):
   ...
```

and

```
from multiprocessing import Process
p = Process(target=lambda: __import__(foo))
    p.start()
def somefunction(foo.firstPoint, someArgs):
   ...
```

and in foo.py I tried:

```
from mainscript import somefunction
firstPoint=(452,68)
someVar=(A,B)
somfunction(someArgs, someVar):
   ...
```

Sorry for the possible bad english, not my native language

Comment: Is the multiprocessing actually part of the issue?

Comment: no, even without it I get the same error